# How to simplify structs using a template?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have a piece of code, copied below, with really similar structs in which just one member changes type. I am looking to simplify it. I was considering using a template, but I am not too sure how would it be the syntax between a struct and a template. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
typedef struct pos_parameter{
    float magnitud;
    bool new_value;
} pos_parameter;

typedef struct feed_parameter{
    double magnitud;
    bool new_value;
} feed_parameter;

typedef struct speed_parameter{
    long magnitud;
    bool new_value;
} speed_parameter;

typedef struct g_code_parameter{
    int magnitud;
    bool new_value;
} g_code_parameter;

typedef struct position{
    pos_parameter X;
    pos_parameter Y;
    pos_parameter Z;
    pos_parameter A;
} position;

typedef struct move{
    position pos;
    feed_parameter feedrate;
    speed_parameter speed;
    g_code_parameter g_code;
} move;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick observation before we get in to genericizing the `magnitud` member variable.  Your use of the `typedef struct {/*...*/} name;` syntax is not needed, and very non-idiomatic in C++.  In C this may be needed, but C++ is not C.  In C++, you can simply:

```
struct Gizmo
{
  /* ... */
};
```

Now, in order to genericize the type of the `magnitud` member variable, you can create a class template like this:

```
template<class MAG> struct basic_parameter
{
    MAG magnitud;
    bool new_value;
};
```

You would declare an instance of such a thing like this:

```
basic_parameter<int> myparam;
```

You can also use a `typedef` to create a kind of "alias" for certian specializations of `basic_parameter`, like this:

```
typedef basic_param<int> int_param;  // Now int_param is shorthand for basic_param<int>
/* ... */
int_param myparam; // myparam is of type basic_param<int>
```

You can use this technique to create `typedef`s for all the different kinds of parameters you were using in the `position` and `move` structures, and make it so that you don't have to change the code for those types.

Here is a complete solution:

```
template<class MAG> struct basic_parameter
{
    MAG magnitud;
    bool new_value;
};

typedef basic_parameter<float> pos_parameter;
typedef basic_parameter<double> feed_parameter;
typedef basic_parameter<long> speed_parameter;
typedef basic_parameter<int> g_code_parameter;

struct position {
    pos_parameter X;
    pos_parameter Y;
    pos_parameter Z;
    pos_parameter A;
};

struct move
{
    position pos;
    feed_parameter feedrate;
    speed_parameter speed;
    g_code_parameter g_code;
};

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T>
struct parameter{
    T magnitud;
    bool new_value;
};
```

Example use:

```
parameter<float> pos_parameter;
parameter<double> feed_parameter;
parameter<long> speed_parameter;
parameter<int> code_parameter;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the first four could be :

```
template<typename T>
struct pos_parameter{
    T magnitud;
    bool new_value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
struct generic_parameter
{
    T magnitud;
    bool new_value;
};
```

There you go